# Data entry screen in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

You may thick that it is a silly question but I am confused!

I have a situation that I have a Lecture table.

And I want to store attendance of who have registered for it.

I have master table of People who will register, lecture table, and Important one table is attendance that stores P.k. as f.k. of rest of the table.

On Index view of lecture operator will select Attendance and enter attendance information.

My problem It show only one page for attendance entry and that page can also open open in **EDIT mode**, for editing attendance.

So what would be the design of the page and process flow of taking attendance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the ways:

1. You can use same page for editing and listing if you define block where are you rendering partial/dynamic block(user control). You need to extend HtmlHelper so you can pass name of a UserControl and you have to from controller pass to view(with ViewData) name of user control you want rendered. This way you can use same template(View/Page) with different actions and different response.
2. You can have editing on client. You can use jQuery UI library to popup dialog box for editing. For posting editing information back, you can use jquery .ajax method. As things happening on client and you request different actions on controller, it doesn't matter how you will approach this in design sense. You can use dialogs, you can transform existing elements on page etc.

Hope this helps